# Python: Printing multiple physical copies of a document?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, printing

Hopefully a simple one, but I can't find any information on using os.startfile(x,"print") anywhere...

```
for i in range(int(quantity)):
    os.startfile(file, "print")
    #print(" Label printed")
print("")
break
```

So the code above is what I'm using to try and get physical copies of "file" printed, based on the number "quantity". But this seems to just open and print one copy?

However, the following code returns the correct number of " Label printed", so I presume the issue is with the actual os.startfile() command.

```
for i in range(int(quantity)):
    #os.startfile(file, "print")
    print(" Label printed")
print("")
break
```

Anyone know how I can do this?

Many thanks

Please see below code for a bit more context...

```
product = "apple"
quantity = "5"
file = r"filepath.docx"

while True:
    print(" Product: ",product)
    print(" Quantity: ",quantity)
    print(" Press 'y' then 'ENTER' to print, or 'c' then 'ENTER' to amend quantity: ")
    continue_print = input(" >>> ")

    if continue_print not in ("y", "c"):
        print(" Please enter 'y' or 'c' \n")
            
    elif continue_print == "y":
        print(" Printing labels...")
        for i in range(int(quantity)):
            #os.startfile(file, "print") # <<< Only prints one copy :\
            print(" Label printed")      # <<< If this line used instead, 
                                         #     will print on screen correct 
                                         #     amount of times...
        print("")
        break
    else:
        while True:
            try:
                quantity = print(" Enter new quantity ")
                quantity = input(" >>> ")
                print("")
                break
            except ValueError:
                print(" Please enter a number \n")
                continue
        continue
```

Comment: Is this on Windows?

Comment: @user56700 - `os.startfile` is [available only on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile)

Comment: Well if you are willing to use pywin32 module, then you could do it this way: `import win32api` `import win32print` `win32api.ShellExecute (0, "print", file, '/d:"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter (), ".", 0)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's still only printing the one copy of the file 